# Get the first line of a string in haxe

Tags: haxe

Let's assume we have a multiline string, like

```
var s:String = "my first line\nmy second line\nmy third line\nand so on!";
```

What is the best way to get (only) the first line of this string in Haxe? I know I can do something like:

```
static function getFirstLine(s:String):String {
    var t:String = s.split("\n")[0];
    if(t.charAt(t.length - 1) == "\r") {
        t = t.substring(0, t.length - 1);
    }
    return t;
}
```

However I'm wondering if there is any easier (predefined) method for this ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat that @Gama11's answer works well and is more elegant than this.

If your string is long, `split` will iterate over the whole thing and allocate an array containing every line in your string, both of which are unnecessary here. Another option would be `indexOf`:

```
static function getFirstLine(s:String):String {
    var i = s.indexOf("\n");
    if (i == -1) return s;
    if (i > 0 && s.charAt(i - 1) == "\r") --i;
    return s.substr(0, i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in utility in the standard library for this that I know of, but you make it a bit more elegant and avoid the `substring()` handling for `\r` by splitting on a regex:

```
static function getFirstLine(s:String):String {
    return ~/\r?\n/.split(s)[0];
}
```

The regex `\r?\n` optionally matches a carriage return followed by a line feed character.